# docker-compose npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start multiple services with docker-compose but I get

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

in my console when I run the docker-compose up command

Note I am able to start the each of the services individually with docker run command.

Below is a copy of my docker-compose.yml file

```js
version: '3.4'

services:
  clientservice:
    image: clientapplication
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  commentservice:
    image: commentsservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./comments/Dockerfile
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  moderationservice:
    image: moderationservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./moderation/Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4003:4003"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  postservice:
    image: postservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./posts/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4000:4000"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  eventbusservice:
    image: eventbus
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./event-bus/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4005:4005"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  queryservice:
    image: queryservice
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./query/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4002:4002"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
networks: 
  blogmicroservice:
    driver: bridge
```

An example of the docker file for individual service

```js
FROM node:12.18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4002
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Do you see any error at layer `npm install`? The start script should be in package.json, so that's strange that docker-compose can run install but cannot find start script

Comment: Can you update the question with file structure? I suspect that the context is not correct

Comment: yes that was the issue.....changed the path in the context and it works fine now

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you see any error at layer `npm install`?

Comment: no ..no errors there .It installs the packages successfully

Comment: ok! that's so strange, if package.json is not there, what is it installing? :)

Comment: There is a package.json file in the root directory containing the folders for the other services .That is where the docker-compose.yml file is also located

Comment: That makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

In the docker-compose file, all services are using the same context

```
build:
  context: .
```

Which means all files will be copied to docker daemon at build time. This is very unlikely to be the case because different apps cannot have the same code base. If each image can be properly run, then the problem may not lie in Dockerfile. You can change context to proper directory:

```
build:
  context: ./your-server
```

Note that *when the value in `context:` supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file. This directory is also the build context that is sent to the Docker daemon.*. So, you may not even need to specify the Dockerfile location.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this ..the context in docker-compose.yml was out of place updated it to this and it startsup fine now

```js
version: '3.4'

services:
  clientservice:
    image: clientapplication
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  commentservice:
    image: commentsservice
    build:
      context: ./comments
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  moderationservice:
    image: moderationservice
    build:
      context: ./moderation
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4003:4003"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  postservice:
    image: postservice
    build:
      context: ./posts
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4000:4000"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  eventbusservice:
    image: eventbus
    build:
      context: ./event-bus
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4005:4005"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
  queryservice:
    image: queryservice
    build: 
      context: ./query
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "4002:4002"
    networks: 
      - blogmicroservice
networks: 
  blogmicroservice:
    driver: bridge
```